# Display content from sub pages

Tags: dotnetnuke

I would like to make sub pages under and existing page.  Lets say the page is "Success Stories" and under this page the user can enter in other pages and format them any way they want.  What I need is a way to make a repeater of all these subpages with stuff like the page title, a little bit of the content, and a button that links to the actual page.

Is this possible out of the box?  I am willing to buy a module if it is reasonable;however a Google search returned no results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option I know is [Child Links from Ventrian.](http://www.ventrian.com/modules/child-links)

You can show all children with title and description & links.  (NOTE: description is Page description NOT content from the page.)

Answer (score 0):

what version of dotnetnuke are you using?

Two options:

### ONE

There is a copy page function where you can choose what modules and setting to copy to the new page.

Under the pages menu - click copy page

then you can select what page to copy from, and then it will list all modules on that page.  You can choose to copy the module with or without content or even reference the module on the source page.

### TWO

Other than that you can create a page template that a user can select that is pre-designed by you.  Create the base page the way you want it and then click export page under the page /  edit page menu depending on your version.  A template will be created in your portal template folder that can be used when creating new pages.

If you are looking to automate this process, then you will have to look into a custom module or design a sql script you can run yourself (but this is a lot more maintenance as it can change with every version.)